# Find error in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, american-english

> Every person in the store **ran** to claim **their** free ice cream **when the bonus prize** was **announced** over the loudspeaker.

I am studying College Composition and found this practice question, which asks me to find the error. Each of the bold sections are possible errors in the sentence. The answer key states that "their" is the error, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Does the answer key give what the 'correct' version should be?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer given is **their** — The outdated rule _Every_... _his/her..._

Answer (score 0):

Only relatively recently has ***their*** been accepted as a singular pronoun. (It still isn't everywhere.)  If you assume that ***their*** is plural, then it would be incorrect, since "every person" requires a singular pronoun.

They are probably expecting ***his*** or ***her*** instead of ***their*** in this context.

Comment: Please watch/check for duplicates before answering.